# Spark:Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o142.saveAsTextFile

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I save a pair rdd by `rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(file_path)`, an error meets.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o142.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1067)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1478)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1478)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1478)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 253, in main
    process()
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2440, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2440, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2440, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 350, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1951, in groupByKey
    merger.mergeCombiners(it)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 288, in mergeCombiners
    self._spill()
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 735, in _spill
    self.serializer.dump_stream([(k, self.data[k])], streams[h])
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 331, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 383, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 634, in dumps
    return zlib.compress(self.serializer.dumps(obj), 1)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 562, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
MemoryError

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 253, in main
    process()
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2440, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2440, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2440, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 350, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/home/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1951, in groupByKey
    merger.mergeCombiners(it)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 288, in mergeCombiners
    self._spill()
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 735, in _spill
    self.serializer.dump_stream([(k, self.data[k])], streams[h])
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 331, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 383, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 634, in dumps
    return zlib.compress(self.serializer.dumps(obj), 1)
  File "/home/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 562, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
MemoryError

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: As you can see from the logs, this is a MemoryError. Please reduce the size of your data or increase the memory configuration you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repartion method is triggering full shuffle, and if the dataset is large driver will result into memory error. Try to increase the number of partitions vaue in repartitton.

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version. By uninstalling 32bit and installing 64bit version solve mine.